# Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: NullPayload on Mule Studio

Tags: twitter, mule

I'm following this tutorial https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/twitter-integration-connector  and when i try tu send a tweet with  updateStatus I get this message  Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: NullPayload ,the show user action works but not the updateStatus

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:twitter="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter/current/mule-twitter.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <twitter:config name="Twitter" accessKey="${twitter.accessKey}" accessSecret="${twitter.accessSecret}" consumerKey="${twitter.consumerKey}" consumerSecret="${twitter.consumerSecret}" streamBaseUrl="https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/" siteStreamBaseUrl="https://sitestream.twitter.com/1.1/" doc:name="Twitter"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" basePath="updateStatus" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="twitterFlow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <twitter:update-status config-ref="Twitter" status="Mensaje" doc:name="Twitter"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

and this is the stacktrace

```
Exception stack is:
1. 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpClientEventFilter$AuthorizationHandler:1623 (null)
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:363 (null)
3. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:282 (null)
4. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: MuleHttpClient$1 (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:190 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
```

The twitter app has read,write and direct message permission ,but i'm not sure about the app website field.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an issue with WWW-authenticate header header in Mule 3.6.x.

I tried a basic twitter flow and it works on Mule 3.5 but not 3.6.

The reported issues are:

- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8282
- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8127
- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8249

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same tutorial and have run into the same issue.  I needed to update the default twitter connector with a new version 4 connector.  The code then worked, however, it will only work once.  To have it work again, I seem to need to change the status message and re-run - otherwise I get the null payload message again.  Just stopping and starting the app doesn't seem to be good enough - I seem to need to change the status.